# SharePoint 2016 on premise - Post Security Trimming not working

Tags: 2016, security-trimming, minrole

Has anyone got Post Security Trimming working in SharePoint 2016? We are moving from a 2013 Farm where the code I'm using worked just fine, in 2016 the trimmer just seems to get totally ignored.

It is setup as per the instructions on the Microsoft site, and works perfectly in 2013.  Get-SPEnterpriseSearchSecurityTrimmer -SearchApplication "Search Service Application" returns the crawl rule path to match, but the trimming just returns all results rather than removing the ones it should. The trimmer code has pretty extensive logging and none of that ever seems to get written out making me think it is never called at all (I have to use custom code as the results are from an non-SharePoint website). I'm not sure it matters but we are running SharePoint in a minrole configuration.

Can anyone confirm they have post security trimming working in SharePoint 2016?  If they do then if they could let me know the steps they took or how it was different to 2013 that would be brilliant.

Thanks for your help!